# CorePlot: How to remove border and padding around graph?

Tags: ios, iphone, core-plot

I am trying to remove and padding around graph:

```
graph.paddingLeft   = 0.0;
graph.paddingTop    = 0.0;
graph.paddingRight  = 0.0;
graph.paddingBottom = 0.0;

[graph setBorderWidth:0.0];
[graph setBorderColor:(__bridge CGColorRef)([CPTColor clearColor])];
```

But I am still having a thin black line rectangle around the graph???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be your `CPTGraphHostingView` border.

To identify this kind of issues, set different border color's for all the related objects and identify them easily.

Try this code to change the borders.

```
[self.hostingView.layer setBorderWidth:2];
[self.hostingView.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]];
```

Comment: In my .h: `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet CPTGraphHostingView *hostingView;`. In my .m: `self.hostingView.hostedGraph = graph;`. Setting color or borderwith on the `CPTGraphHostingView`, doesn't compile in Xcode...

Comment: use this code,  [self.hostingView.layer setBorderWidth:2];
                [self.hostingView.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]];

Comment: This code draws a blue border around the graph, but includes the padding.Tx.